# How to count each group of values in a dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary, counting

I have a dictionary with multiple values under multiple keys.  I do NOT want a single sum of the values.  I want to find a way to find the sum for each key.
The file is tab delimited, with an identifier being a combination of two of these items, Btarg.  There are multiple values for each of these identifiers.
Here is a test file:
Here is a test file with the desired result below:

Pattern Item    Abundance

1        Ant 2

2            Dog 10

3          Giraffe   15

1            Ant 4

2            Dog 5

Here is the expected results:

Pattern1Ant, 6

Pattern2Dog, 15

Pattern3Giraffe, 15

This is what I have so far:

```
for line in K:

    if "pattern" in line:
        find = line
        Bsplit = find.split("\t")
        Buid = Bsplit[0]
        Borg = Bsplit[1]
        Bnum = (Bsplit[2])
        Btarg = Buid[:-1] + "//" + Borg


        if Btarg not in dict1:
            dict1[Btarg] = []
        dict1[Btarg].append(Bnum)
    #The following used to work
    #for key in dict1.iterkeys():
        #dict1[key] = sum(dict1[key])
    #print (dict1)
```

How do I make this work in Python 3 without the error message "Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, include the full traceback of your error, and the expected output of your code.

Comment: `Buid[:-3]`: this is list slicing syntax. What that's saying is "give me a list of all the elements in Buid up to and including the third one from the end". Then you're trying to add that list to a string (`"//"`) which gives you the error.

Comment: The error message for the above statement, is "dict object has no attribute iterkeys".
When I change the code to dict.items() (instead of dict1.iterkeys()), it gives this error: unhashable type, 'list'

Comment: Lanaru- even if I change it to just Buid it still gives me an error, only now its unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1):

Use `from collections import Counter`

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
c = Counter('gallahad')
Counter({'a': 3, 'l': 2, 'h': 1, 'g': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Responding to your comment, now I think I know what you want, although I don't know what structure you have your data in. I will take for granted that you can organize your data like this:

```
In [41]: d
Out[41]: [{'Ant': 2}, {'Dog': 10}, {'Giraffe': 15}, {'Ant': 4}, {'Dog': 5}]
```

First create a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(int)
```

Then start couting:

```
In [42]: for each in d:
            a[each.keys()[0]] += each.values()[0]
```

Result:

```
In [43]: a
Out[43]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Ant': 6, 'Giraffe': 15, 'Dog': 15})
```

**UPDATE 2**

Supposing you can get your data in this format:

```
In [20]: d
Out[20]: [{'Ant': [2, 4]}, {'Dog': [10, 5]}, {'Giraffe': [15]}]

In [21]: from collections import defaultdict

In [22]: a = defaultdict(int)

In [23]: for each in d:
    a[each.keys()[0]] =sum(each.values()[0])
   ....:     

In [24]: a
Out[24]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Ant': 6, 'Giraffe': 15, 'Dog': 15})
```

Comment: I have tried to implement Counter, but when I put dict1 or dict1.values to replace 'gallahad', I do not get any totals.

Comment: No, if you add a dictionary, you get a new Counter. What you want is to place your keys or values in a list and use Counter directly on them. Read the documentation. There are several examples there. By the way, do the counting outside your loop.

Comment: Went through the documentation and still am receiving errors.  This is usually why I do not use Counter.  Sorry

Comment: Hmm, thanks Robert for being more precise.  However, this example and all of those in the documentation, are counting a string, and then reporting it with the name of the string and the count.  But, I want to count the counts of some defined pattern, ie summing totals and not counting the occurrence.  I will work on tweaking this.  Thanks again

Comment: Can you implement a for each key mechanism for counter?  I tried this with no success


for key in dict1.items():

        my_list.append(dict1.values)

from collections import Counter

Counter(my_list)

Comment: Did you change your dict1 for a defaultdict? Counter doesn't seem a good option here, anyway.

Comment: For some reason when I enter a[each.keys()[0]] += each.values()[0], it gives me the error:  'str' object has no attribute 'keys'.  Why is the defaultdict being registered as a string?

Comment: You must be using iterkeys in your loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, Im not using iterkeys, those dont work in python 3.
Im not sure if it matters, but my dictionary has been appended for each key.  So unlike your example that has two "ant" keys with different values, mine has one ant key with two values in it.
Also, is the "In [42]:" supposed to be a part of the code?

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe that will help you. In any case, you need to be able to restructure your data in a way that allows easy computations.